# What is the better solution if I want multiple form for the same entity?

Tags: forms, symfony

As I said in my title, imagine I have one entity User and I want to create multiple form for this entity.

For example, this is my class User :

```
class User
{
    protected $firstname;
    protected $lastname;
    protected $sex;
    protected $birthdate
    protected $phone;
    protected $email;
    protected $password;
}
```

Now I want to create multiple form for this entity :

- RegisterForm (ask every fields)
- ConnexionForm (ask email + password)
- ForgetPasswordForm (ask email)
- etc.

I find this solution and I'd like to know if it's the best practice or not :

In my "FormType", I configure my options like this :

```
/**
* @param OptionsResolver $resolver
*/
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User',
        'fields' => false,
    ));
}
```

Then I create a loop for each fields I want :

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    if($options['fields']){
       foreach($options['fields'] as $field){
                   $builder->add($field);
       }
    } else {
          // Every field I want
    }


}
```

And in my Controller, I can use it like this :

```
$form  = $this->createForm(UserType::class,$user,['fields' => ['email','password', 'other...']);
```

With the same idea, I maybe can give a name to my different form and if I don't write a name in my "options" I create the "Register" form, if I write "connexion" I build the "Connexion" form, etc.

Do you have a better solution or it's the best way to do it?

(I know you can do it with FOSUserBundle, but I pick "User" for the example)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like you wrote.

But i think better solution is to write specialized php form classes.
Than you would have types like you wrote. But form classes are called with Type word in Symfony:

- RegisterType (ask every fields)
- ConnectionType (ask email + password)
- ForgetPasswordType (ask email)

Here you have Best Practices and more tips from Symfony (first paragraph is about forms):
http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/best_practices/forms.html

Comment: Thanks to anwser. So the best solution is to repeat almost the same code 3 times (in my example) and just change the fields I need? This is what I wanted to do first, but in my mind if you repeat yourself you don't optimize your code :s But if the Symfony best-practices are ok with that I think I will just follow the advices ^^

Comment: If you really won't change much in this classes and you feel it really breaks DRY you could use the options resolver as you  point in your post. Sometimes i use it too. If you do so you should remember to put buttons in the view where you use your form. As they say in this paragraph: http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/best_practices/forms.html#form-button-configuration

Comment: Since each form is very different in function, I think multiple form classes is the best solution.  I know you're trying to not repeat your code, but at some point that gets taken to the extreme and you end up doing a bunch of tricks that may work but make your code a lot less clear.  If I were looking to modify a registration form, I'd be looking for a RegisterType class, not a generic UserType class.